# How to extract html table by using Beautifulsoup

Tags: python, html, html-parsing, beautifulsoup, parent

Taking the below html snippet as example:

```
>>>soup
<table>
<tr><td class="abc">This is ABC</td>
</tr>
<tr><td class="firstdata"> data1_xxx </td>
</tr>
</table>

<table>
<tr><td class="efg">This is EFG</td>
</tr>
<tr><td class="firstdata"> data1_xxx </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

If I can only find my desire table by its table data class,

```
>>>soup.findAll("td",{"class":"abc"})
[<td class="abc">This is ABC</td>]
```

how can I extract the whole table as below?

```
<table>
<tr><td class="abc">This is ABC</td>
</tr>
<tr><td class="firstdata"> data1_xxx </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get the `td` tag's [`parent`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#parent) using [`find_parent()`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#find-parents-and-find-parent):

```
soup.find("td", {"class":"abc"}).find_parent('table')
```

Demo:

```
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
>>> data = """
... <div>
...     <table>
...         <tr><td class="abc">This is ABC</td>
...         </tr>
...         <tr><td class="firstdata"> data1_xxx </td>
...         </tr>
...     </table>
... 
...     <table>
...         <tr><td class="efg">This is EFG</td>
...         </tr>
...         <tr><td class="firstdata"> data1_xxx </td>
...         </tr>
...     </table>
... </div>
... """
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup(data)
>>> print soup.find("td", {"class":"abc"}).find_parent('table')
<table>
<tr><td class="abc">This is ABC</td>
</tr>
<tr><td class="firstdata"> data1_xxx </td>
</tr>
</table>
```