# How to extract table data from html file with BeautifulSoup?

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup, html-parsing

I am trying to clean up some data I have to prep it for moving it into a database. I am not a programmer by trade, so this is all new to me. I have been scouring the site trying to find sample code to try. I found this discussion and as you can see, I tried to adapt my situation to it:
[How to extract html table by using Beautifulsoup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23809640/how-to-extract-html-table-by-using-beautifulsoup)

```
<html>
<head>
<title>This the title.</title>
</head>
<body>
<center>
<br />
<br />
<h2>Test Case 1</h2>
</center>
<table align="center" border="1" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="1" width="650">
<tr>
<td>
<font size="1"> Cell Title 1</font>
<br /> </td>
<td>
<font size="1"> Cell Title 2</font>
<br /> </td>
<td>
<font size="1"> Cell Title 3</font>
<br /> 
<font size="2">Value</font></td>
<td>
<font size="1"> Cell Title4</font>
<br /> 
<font size="2">Value</font></td>
```

Here is the error:

> Traceback (most recent call last): File "ExtractTest2.py", line 35, in
>    print soup.find("td", {"size":"2"}).find_parent('table')
>   AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find_parent'

My ultimate goal is to print out

```
Cell Title X : Value
```

if there is a Value as there will be a Cell Title.

Where did I go wrong?

Comment: Please post the code from ExtractTest2.py

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> `soup.find("td", {"size":"2"})`

The main problem is here - no `td` element in your HTML has a `size` attribute.

Instead, check the `size` on a `font` element. Sample code:

```
for title in soup.find_all("font", {"size": "1"}):
    value = title.find_next_sibling("font", {"size": "2"})

    print title.text, " | ", value.text if value else "No Value"
```

Prints:

```
 Cell Title 1  |  No Value
 Cell Title 2  |  No Value
 Cell Title 3  |  Value
 Cell Title4  |  Value
```

Comment: @alexce That did the trick. I tried reading the BS4 documentation. I will go over again and ask questions in a new post. Thanks!!